# How to specify package structure in VSTS to get the files from multiple locations but still maintaining the flat file structure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My Project structure is as follows:

`src\ProjectName\bin\`**Debug** or **Release**

There are also some config files at `src\ProjectName`

I need to copy files from both the locations specified above to the path `C:\$(System.TeamProject)\$(Build.SourceBranchName)\package`

I do want to preserve the folder structure under `src\ProjectName\bin\`**Debug** or **Release** and also want to have config files from `src\ProjectName` to be copied to the destination.

How should I approach this copy task in VSTS?

Comment: Do you mean you just want preserve the folder structure in Debug or Release folder, do not preserve the src\ProjectName\bin folder structure? Could you provide a detail sample for your requirement? Is src folder in the source directory ($(build.sourcesdirectory) e.g. d:\1\s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use Copy Files task. Detail settings as below:

**Contents:**

```
src\ProjectName\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**
src\ProjectName\*.config
```

**Target Folder:** `C:\$(System.TeamProject)\$(Build.SourceBranchName)\package`

Then it will copy specified files to the target folder and keep the related folder structure.

**Note:** the variable `$(BuildConfiguration)` is usually stand for debug/release. If your build definition has not the variable, you can add it. For the `*.config` is match the config files you need to copy, if your config files are not this pattern, you can change it.